# How to customize a theme's navigation menu with css

Tags: css

i would want to customize the navigation menu so that its dropdown-menu stays active all the time, i don't want it to appear on hover, but when the page of the active main menu item has loaded and the submenu should remain visible. So when the home page loads it's submenu should be visible just like at www.dailymail.co.uk

could anyone assist with the custom css that i can use

Comment: Could you please share me your site URL where it's displaying so that i can help you to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress automatically generates "current-menu-item" class to the menu of the current page you visit. So in this case, you can do something like-

```
.current-menu-item ul.sub-menu { display: block !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks Neit....however the submenu is only becoming active after i click on at menu item.

how do i make the Home menu item active by refreshing the front page?

Answer (score 1):

We have created a CodePen to demonstrate how you can achieve that  using HTML/CSS/JS. Hope that will help you.

https://codepen.io/mervanagency/pen/XRKxwr